# GCC: disguising between GCC versions

Tags: gcc, linux-kernel, version, driver, nvidia

This question was emerged from [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34043/nvidia-driver-for-the-3-2-9-kernel) question.

The problem is that there is a `NVidia` driver for `Linux`, compiled wth `GCC 4.5`. The `kernel` is compiled with `GCC 4.6`. Well, the stuff doesn't work because of the version number difference between `GCCs`. (the installer says the driver won't work - for details please visit the link above)

Could one disguise a binary compiled with `GCC 4.5` to a binary compiled with `GCC 4.6`? If it is possible, under what circumstances would it work well?

Comment: Doesn't work as in refuses to load or crashes or...?

Comment: Why not just recompile the kernel with GCC 4.5?

Comment: Let me mention that the original problem is not mine. The installer says that versions are inappropriate. I suggested at the UNIX/Linux site the kernel recompilation, but I am curious how to solve the problem without it.

Watch this as an abstract problem: when will $progname.$gccversion1 work, if we disguise it to $progname.$gccversion2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is called ABI: Application Binary Interface. This is a set of rules (among others) how functions in a piece of code get their arguments (ordering, padding of types on the stack), naming of the function so the linker can resolve symbols and padding/alignment of fields in structures.

GCC tries to keep the ABI stable between compiler versions but that's not always possible.

For example, [GCC 4.4 fixed a bug in packed bit-fields](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/changes.html#obsoleted) which means that old/new code can't read structures using this feature properly anymore. If you would mix versions before and after 4.4, data corruption would occur without any crashes.

There is no indication in the 4.6 release notes that the ABI was changed but that's something which the Linux kernel can't know - it just reads the compiler version used to compile the code and if the first two numbers change, it assumes that running the code isn't safe.

There are two solutions:

1. You can compile the Nvidia driver with the same compiler as the kernel. **This is strongly recommended**
2. You can patch the version string in the binary. This will trick the kernel into loading the module but at the risk of causing data corruption to internal data structures.

Comment: is it more important the the kernel and driver are compiled with the same gcc version, or the driver and the program, or all 3 need the same?

Comment: It's important that all three are compiled with the same ABI. You can have a kernel compiled with 4.6 and a program compiled with 4.7 without problems.